# iOS enterprise distribution 4g download limit？

Tags: ios, app-store, 4g, enterprise-distribution

We know AppStore has a limitation that we can't download apps larger than 100MB via 4g.However I came across the same issue when I was installing an app for enterprise distribution which is over 100MB. The app is waiting all the time unless I change network to WIFI.

So my question is,does enterprise distribution apps have 100MB limitation in 4G too?Any documents for reference?

Comment: I don't know if it is documented anywhere, I think it is just that app installations of any kind, from any source are limited to 100MB unless on WiFi or via a USB cable.  It is a limit imposed by the app installation process on iOS, not by the App Store.

Comment: I think so.The weird thing is I will get a warning in AppStore while nothing but loading forever in enterprise distribution.Perhaps a mistake by Apple developer.